# What happened to the "tour" button?

Tags: support, bug

I believe this picture should help understand the issue at hand :

[image: Picture showing the connexion]
<sup>Tour button? Toouurr buuttooon?</sup>

I cannot find the button to reach the tour anymore, even though it is still accessible by direct access and existing links ([like here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)). This happens both logged in and logged out, on meta and on main, on mobile phone and on PC, for a total of 4 web browsers tested. It is not reachable through the help-center, either.

Since we can still technically reach the page and the button is quite important to newcomers, I currently believe it's a bug. So what happened to the easy-to-access tour button? Any fix in the foreseeable future?

Comment: Maybe worth posting in Meta

Comment: @L.Dutch I tried on other SE sites, I have the same issue, so indeed it could be more general than I thought. I'll post the same query on hyper-meta, between the two or three hot topics about moderators and staff leaving o_x.

Comment: Poeple already talked about it on meta, visibly : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393737/the-tour-link-has-disappeared-from-the-help-menu-in-the-top-bar . I know I dislike going on super-meta (and so may others), so I'll leave this post here and update it if anything happens there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was temporary and has been fixed/"no longer reproducible".

Comment: @Joachim It's not really part of the process to close bug "questions" which have been solved (when solved you just mark an answer as accepted, see meta's meta's own "questions"), but I don't think that's really important :).

Comment: I thought it was, especially since it was a network-wide bug, and more appropriate for Meta—but maybe I'm confusing it with *their* policy :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This has been fixed

[From meta's meta, it has been told the issue has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393877/1095559). And as far as I know, I can confirm we see again the recomforting "Tour" button, allowing us to bask in its glorious light again :

[image: Picture of the menu with the button to reach the tour. All hail the "Tour" button!]

Please tell in comment (or by default, in answer) if you still have the issue, so we can report it has not been solved for you .

Comment: I would never have looked there for the [tour] link. I've always found it at the bottom of the page along with the [help], [chat], and contact links. But it's now gone from that location. Hiding the [tour] link under that question mark in the menu bar simply obfuscates it. Stack Exchange has made too many (IMO) bad decisions recently in the design of the UI. In the quest to clean it up, they've made it harder to use (I'm including bugs in that claim).

Comment: @JBH [The tour link is there on the main site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH43Z.png) but not on meta. I don't recall if it was visible on meta or not before.

Comment: @JBH It has been moved on the top by following this concept of UI design that people using the latin alphabet scans content from left-to-right and top-to-bottom. That's why the site name+logo is at the top-left (most important info+link), the menu on the left and every important option at the top-right. The help button is shown most of the time as question marks, nowadays. So most users will actually click the buttons at the top first. We (I and you) are actually one of the few to look and search for footers, probably because that's where you always get both legal and in-depth stuff.

Comment: As for why it's not visible on meta, my intuition is that the code, unit tests and just general testing is not very clean on the front-side -as this blazing bug I reported showcased-. But I'm not an SE developer, so that's only 2 cents thrown in the wind ^^.

Comment: That's a good point. It's there on Main. That's weird.